# Populate PHP Chart from Text File

Tags: javascript, php, html, charts, populate

Here is my first request after using this great community when I was stuck in my project, I admit that it helped me a lot :)

ATM i'm trying to populate data from text file to Chart (PHP) but I'm not very comfortable to manage it from a text file.

Here is the data into my txt file :

```html
     // DATE\\          //QUALIF\\ //NumTicket\\   //NAME\\
[2016-04-26 12:56:07]  -  Qualif 1 -  674566  -  interne-xxx
[2016-04-26 12:57:58]  -  Qualif 2 -  674567  -  interne-xxx
[2016-04-27 14:12:39]  -  Qualif 3 -  674596  -  interne-zzz
[2016-04-28 14:25:35]  -  Qualif 4 -  674601  -  interne-xxx
[2016-04-28 17:05:28]  -  Qualif 5 -  674682  -  interne-yyy
[2016-04-28 12:56:07]  -  Qualif 5 -  674566  -  interne-zzz
[2016-04-29 12:57:58]  -  Qualif 2 -  674567  -  interne-yyy
[2016-04-29 14:12:39]  -  Qualif 2 -  674596  -  interne-yyy
[2016-04-30 14:25:35]  -  Qualif 4 -  674601  -  interne-xxx
[2016-04-30 17:05:28]  -  Qualif 5 -  674682  -  interne-zzz
```

What I would like is a result (statistic) to Graph :

**== Number of "Qualif" per day ==**

- 2016-04-26 : 1 x Qualif 1 / 1 x Qualif 2
- 2016-04-27 : 1 x Qualif 3
- 2016-04-28 : 1 x Qualif 4 / 2 x Qualif 5
- 2016-04-29 : 2 x Qualif 2
- 2016-04-30 : 1 x Qualif 4 / 1 x Qualif 5

**== Number of "NAME" per day ==**

- 2016-04-26 : 2 x interne-xxx
- 2016-04-27 : 1 x interne-zzz
- 2016-04-28 : 1 x interne-xxx / 1 x interne-yyy / 1 x interne-zzz
- 2016-04-29 : 2 x interne-yyy
- 2016-04-30 : 1 x interne-xxx / 1 x interne-zzz

My goal is to create a page that will read my txt file and then extract the data to create me a graph of this data.

And I would like if possible to be able to select the information by days, like as a dashboard.

What is your advice please and without using SQL base ??

Thank you very much in advance, best regards.

Comment: You can use the amChart for creating chart or graph. amChart has many options to manage your requirements. It will create graph based on your data. [here is link](https://www.amcharts.com/)

Comment: Hi, well thank you for the link :)

Perhaps you can provide me one working example, please ?

Comment: Yes, of coerce why not. [working demo example](http://codepen.io/team/amcharts/pen/c7ea7350acd1d78b4e17f7060f04c8b6)

Comment: Thank you for your help ! But in your example you are using an array and in my case i need ti use data from text file. Can you manage it ?

Regards.

Comment: You can convert your text file to JSON based on data.

Comment: Sorry to reply lately ! I have opted to use a DB SQL for my charts because is easier to manage it :)

BTW thanks you for the help !